# Can't read even though there is dylib symbol

Tags: macos, dylib, dl4j, nd4j

I get this error when running my java program.
(on intellij ide.)

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   ___emutls_get_address   Referenced from: /Users/xxx/.javacpp/cache/nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta5-macosx-x86_64.jar/org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libnd4jcpu.dylib
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address   Referenced from:
>   /Users/xxx/.javacpp/cache/nd4j-native-1.0.0-beta5-macosx-x86_64.jar/org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libnd4jcpu.dylib
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

I checked the `/usr/lib/` path but `libSystem.B.dylib` exists.

Do you have a solution?

Postscript
I was able to run the same version of DL4J (ND4J) on the same mac.
However, after updating mac and xcode, this error came out soon.

`xcode-select --install` has been executed.

Comment: After upgrading the version of the org.deeplearning4j from 1.0.0-beta5 to 1.0.0-beta6 it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try latest DL4J snapshots, this problem should be resolved there.
Instructions: https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-config-snapshots

Comment: i'm tried it. but other error received. ```Referenced from: /Users/xxx/.javacpp/cache/nd4j-native-1.0.0-20191116.014620-15875-macosx-x86_64.jar/org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libjnind4jcpu.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib```
  (it's exists)
Is this a different error  from the error that the file does not exist?

Comment: Thanks for flagging this one. I've applied one more fix, so next shapshots build show work fine. Please let me know if there'll be any other problems.

Comment: Thank you!
The latest snapshot version has useable successfully!